# spring security oauth issue with SSL

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

Everything works on HTTP but when I enable SSL with certificate I can't access token with error:

```
{
error: "invalid_client",
error_description: "Bad client credentials"
}
```

My AuthServer config class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Service
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationManager authenticationManager; //my custom auth manager

    @Autowired
    private CommonConfig configService; //my config service 

    @Autowired
    private MemoryTokenStore tokenStore;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()").checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()")
                .allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory().withClient(configService.getClientId()).authorizedGrantTypes("password")
                .scopes(configService.getAuthScopes()).resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(configService.getTokenValiditySc()).secret(configService.getClientSecret());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager).allowedTokenEndpointRequestMethods(HttpMethod.GET)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

}
```

spring boot v1.5.8. How can I fix it ?

Comment: Did you import your cert into the cacert file under the jre that you are using to run tomcat?

Comment: yes I did, service works, only oauth/token does not work